# JavaScript to auto-calculate man-hours in 24-time for Adobe Form Field?

Tags: javascript, forms, time, adobe

I run a landscape crew and instead of filling out our forms manually I would like to do it via cellphone and have the times auto-calculated in the form fields. I'm *not* familiar with JavaScript and need some assistance in getting the correct code in order to calculate the crew times and total site man-hours *without* this error when I change the times. *Note:* I will use 24-hour time.

[image: Example of Input Error]

I tried a few different JavaScript snippets I discovered and though they work I am getting a format error when manipulating the time input. Any suggestions on how to script this into Adobe?

**To generate the employee times I use the code below:**

**UPDATE EDIT THIS IS GENERATING INCORRECT TIMES:**
[image: Time Calculation Error]

```
// start
var start = this.getField("Monday Site #1 Start Time").value;
var startArr = start.split(":");

// finish
var finish = this.getField("Monday Site #1 Depart Time").value;
var finishArr = finish.split(":");

// difference
var hourDiff = Math.abs(finishArr[0] - startArr[0]);
var minDiff = Math.floor((Math.abs(finishArr[1] - startArr[1]) / 60)*100);

if (minDiff.toString().length == 1) 
    minDiff = '0' + minDiff;

var output = hourDiff + "." + minDiff;
event.value = output;

if ((event.value == "") || (event.value == Infinity) || isNaN(event.value)) {

  event.value = "";}
```

**To calculate the total site time (total manhours for the specific site) I used this:**

```
var t1 = this.getField("WS1 Total").value;
var t2 = this.getField("WS1 Total").value;
var t3 = this.getField("WS1 Total").value;
event.value = t1+t2+t3
```

Comment: What is the format for the form field you are attempting to update?

Comment: Standard time format of HH:MM

Comment: And what is the format of `event.value`?

Comment: Thanks ksav! Changed to No Format and this got rid of the errors. *However* while field testing the forms today I noticed the time calculations are not correct. See update edit above. Should I make a new post for this?

Comment: I'm not sure what the error is here. What are you expecting `2.18 + 2.18 + 2.18` to equal?

Comment: The error is 06:24am-08:13am does not equal 2.18 hours. Total man-hours field calculation is correct but the employee calculation, or calculation based on start and depart times are incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [calculate the elapsed time between two Javascript Date objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Calculating_elapsed_time) in milliseconds like this:

```js
function timeDiff(startTime, endTime) {
  var startArr = startTime.split(":");
  var endArr = endTime.split(":");
  var startDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, startArr[0], startArr[1], 0);
  var endDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, endArr[0], endArr[1], 0);
  var diff = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
  var hours = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60 / 60);
  diff -= hours * 1000 * 60 * 60;
  var minutes = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60);
  return hours + ":" + (minutes < 9 ? "0" : "") + minutes;
}

console.log(timeDiff('6:24', '8:13')) // 1:49
```

Or if you want to return hours as decimal.

```js
function timeDiff(startTime, endTime) {
    var startArr = startTime.split(":");
    var endArr = endTime.split(":");
    var startDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, startArr[0], startArr[1], 0);
    var endDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, endArr[0], endArr[1], 0);
    var diff = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
    var hours = diff / 1000 / 60 / 60;
    return hours.toFixed(2)
}

console.log(timeDiff('6:24', '8:13')) // 1.82
```

I'm guessing that you can then do something like this:

```
var finish = this.getField("Monday Site #1 Depart Time").value;
var start = this.getField("Monday Site #1 Start Time").value;

this.getField("MS1T").value = timeDiff(start, finish);
```

Comment: I tried these snippets in the custom script of adobe but they give me no calculations. Keep in mind I am manually entering the times as I leave and arrive via Form Field in PDF. Forgive me for being a nub at JavaScript but these form fields should match the variables right? [Fields](https://i202.photobucket.com/albums/aa60/dmknappy/Fields.jpg)

Comment: You should be able to add this function, and use it as a helper to calculate the `employee calculation`. You would need to call that function with your start time and end time like this `timeDiff('6:24', '8:13');`

Comment: Granted the snippet does work the final calculation is incorrect. [For example see my other post which hasn't been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58683495/miscalculation-of-decimal-hours-worked-via-javascript-in-adobe-form-fill)

Comment: Can you please elaborate on which calculation is incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

This worked, with a tweak for NaN:

```js
var start = this.getField("Monday Site #1 Depart Time").value;
var finish = this.getField("Monday Site #2 Depart Time").value;

this.getField("MS1 Total").value = timeDiff(start, finish);

if ((event.value == "") || (event.value == Infinity) || isNaN(event.value)) {event.value = "";}
```