# Miscalculation of decimal hours worked via JavaScript in Adobe Form Fill

Tags: javascript, time, adobe, difference, calculation

First, I give thanks to [ksav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5385381/ksav) and his [help thus far](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58261419/javascript-to-auto-calculate-man-hours-in-24-time-for-adobe-form-field).

I'm a foreman for a landscaping company and it's my responsibility to fill out forms for each site and keep track of our man hours so we don't go over the allotted time. I'm *trying* to digitize the documents in Adobe so I can enter the times in the field on my phone without pen and paper and have a JavaScript code automatically calculate the hours on site in decimal format.

**Note:** I *will* be using 24-hour time aka military time (13:00/1PM 16:40/4:40PM)

#### The JS code currently used within Adobe isn't calculating/converting the time difference correctly:

[image: SECOND]

#### This gives **incorrect** decimal calculations on the time difference:

```
var start = this.getField("Monday Site #1 Start Time").value;
var startArr = start.split(":");

// finish
var finish = this.getField("Monday Site #1 Depart Time").value;
var finishArr = finish.split(":");

// difference
var hourDiff = Math.abs(finishArr[0] - startArr[0]);
var minDiff = Math.floor((Math.abs(finishArr[1] - startArr[1]) / 59)*100);

if (minDiff.toString().length == 1) 
    minDiff = '0' + minDiff;

var output = hourDiff + "." + minDiff;
event.value = output;

if ((event.value == "") || (event.value == Infinity) || isNaN(event.value)) 
    {event.value = "";}
```

## Examples of the hour-decimal calculation errors:

[image: TEST]

I should mention these fields are **all uniquely named Form Fill fields** within Adobe, hence the variable field names "Monday Site #1 Start Time, Monday Site #1 Depart Time, MS1 Total Hours etc etc:

[image: Form Fields]

[See my original question where I tried other JS code to no avail. Some of those snippets didn't give me any value whatsoever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58261419/javascript-to-auto-calculate-man-hours-in-24-time-for-adobe-form-field)

**I have limited knowledge on JavaScript code so any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated!**